# Redshift: Update one table using another table with JOIN vs without JOIN

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to update some columns of tableA with corresponding values from tableB.

Are the following two update queries equivalent? (Does the first query use an implicit JOIN?)

**Query 1 (without explicit JOIN):**

```
UPDATE tableA
SET col1 = tb.col1, col2 = tb.col2
FROM tableB tb
WHERE tb.col3 = tableA.col3
```

**Query 2 (with explicit JOIN):**

```
UPDATE tableA
SET col1 = tb.col1, col2 = tb.col2
FROM tableB tb JOIN tableA ta ON ta.col3=tb.col3
```

Answer (score 1):

The tables are **not** equivalent.

The second query has two separate references to `TableA`.  There is no correlation clause between the `tableA` in the `update` and the `FROM` clause.  So, every row is going to attempt to be updated with the *all* the rows that result from the `FROM` clause.

No doubt, you intend the first version.

Also note that in SQL Server, the two would be equivalent -- even with the `ta` table alias.  SQL Server ignores that.